# String indices in Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground, swift2

I decided to learn Swift and I decided to start with Swift 2 right away.

So here is a very basic example that's similar to one of the examples from Apple's own e-book about Swift

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag"

for index in indices(greeting) {
    print(greeting[index])
}
```

I tried this in the playground of Xcode 7 and I received the following error

> Cannot invoke 'indices' with an argument list of type '(String)'

I also tried the same thing with Xcode 6 (which is Swift 1.2 AFAIK) and it worked as expected.

Now, my question is: Is this

1. An error in Xcode 7, it's still a beta release after all, or
2. Something that just doesn't work anymore with Swift 2 and the e-book just isn't fully updated yet?

Also: If the answer is "2", how would you replace `indices(String)` in Swift 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a Playground, if you go to menu View > Debug Area > Show debug area, you can see the full error in the console:

> /var/folders/2q/1tmskxd92m94__097w5kgxbr0000gn/T/./lldb/94138/playground29.swift:5:14: error: 'indices' is unavailable: access the 'indices' property on the collection
>   for index in indices(greeting)

Also, `String`s do not conform to `SequenceType`s anymore, but you can access their elements by calling `characters`.

**So the solution for Swift 2 is to do it like this:**

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag"

for index in greeting.characters.indices {
    print(greeting[index])
}
```

Result:

> G
>   u
>   t
>   e
>   n
>
> T
>   a
>   g

Of course, I assume your example is just to test `indices`, but otherwise you could just do:

```
for letter in greeting.characters {
    print(letter)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I was just testing `indices` and already aware of the easier solution since `characters` is mentioned earlier in the book. Also your hint about the debugging console was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, I did hesitate about adding this last comment as I was pretty sure you were aware of it. :) But I added it eventually because I thought it could help future readers to be sure the topic of the post was `indices` and not actually accessing the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion, I have found a very simple way to get characters and substrings out of strings *(this is not my code, but I can't remember where I got it from)*:

include this String extension in your project:

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        return substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex), end: startIndex.advancedBy(r.endIndex)))
    }
}
```

this will enable you to do:

```
print("myTest"[3]) //the result is "e"
print("myTest"[1...3]) //the result is "yTe"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that you looking:

```
var middleName :String? = "some thing"
for index in (middleName?.characters.indices)! {
// do some thing with index
}
```